# bottle: global routing filter

Tags: python, routes, bottle

I'M using bottle for a simple app that displays a calendar, and allows the user to specify the year and the month. The following routes are defined:

'/' # current year and current month

'/year' # year and current month

'/year/month' # year and month

However, routes that have an extra / at the end aren't recognized. E.g. '/2015' is ok, but '/2015/' isn't. In order to overcome this, I used a regex [routing filter](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html). This works, but makes me define a pattern for each route, and then check explicitly if the route ends with '/'. I'd like to define a global filter which removes the extra slash from the end of the request url (if such exists).

```
from bottle import route, run, template
import calendar
import time

CAL = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
Y, M = time.strftime('%Y %m').split()

@route('/')
@route('/<year:re:\d{4}/?>')
@route('/<year>/<month:re:\d{1,2}/?>')
def cal(year = Y, month = M):
    y = year if year[-1] != '/' else year[:-1]
    m = month if month[-1] != '/' else month[:-1]
    return template(CAL.formatmonth(int(y), int(m))) 

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating duplicate routes, I would suggest enforcing a strict url schema with urls ending with slashes and encouraging clients to use it by redirecting from urls not ending with a slash, for example using the following route:

```
@route('<path:re:.+[^/]$>')
def add_slash(path):
    return redirect(path + "/")
```

(BTW, this is django's [default behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#append-slash)).

Comment: Thx! It worked after adding `redirect` to the imports

Comment: Use HTTP code 301 (permanent redirection): `return redirect(path + '/', 301)`

Answer (score 2):

The Bottle docs mention your very question, and here's what they suggest:

> add a WSGI middleware that strips trailing slashes from all URLs

or

> add a `before_request` hook to strip the trailing slashes

Examples of both can be [found in the docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#ignore-trailing-slashes).